# How to add values in UNIX?

Tags: shell, unix, arithmetic-expressions

I am new to Unix. I tried to add values as mentioned below:

```
var='expr 2 + 2'
echo "Total value: $var"
```

I expect the output to be `Total value: 4`.  Instead I am getting `Total value: expr 2 + 2`.

Could anyone help me to identify my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplified approach :

```
var=$((2 + 2))
```

---

Or `bc` (calculator language) approach to perform math calculations:

```
var=$(echo '2 + 2' | bc)
echo "Total value: $var"
Total value: 4
```

Comment: Looks like overkill to me - `expr` is just fine.  The important thing is the command substitution, using `\`command\`` or `$(command)`

Comment: @TobySpeight, `var=$((2 + 2))` is even better (portability). `bc` is good for extended math calculations

Comment: Remember to use `bc -l` if you use decimal (non-integer) numbers.

Comment: I always forget that arithmetic substitution is standard - it always seems like the kind of thing that would be Bash-only for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know one shell concept: when you write `var='expr 2 + 2'`, that's a string. But you want to have the result of this command. 
For that, you need to write `$(expr 2 + 2)` to execute the command, and substitute its output.

Here's a working replacement:

```
var=$(expr 2 + 2)
echo "Total value: $var"
```

Welcome to the Unix world! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var=$(expr "2" + "2")
echo "Total value: $var"
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way:

```
var=$(( 2 + 2 ))
echo "Total value: $var"
```

(EDIT: not calling it a bashism)

Comment: bashism?  Really?

Comment: Arithmetic expansions (`$(( ... ))`) are POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer accordingly, not calling it a bashism anymore.